# How to load and show markers on the map from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

is possible to load more values (X and Y) from MySQL and show multiple rectangles on single image?(all together) - Sorry for my english, i'm romanian.
For example, i want to show like this: https://panel.bigzone.ro/qmap/ .
And my code for one rectangle to show is:

```
    <?php

$img = imagecreatefromjpeg("map.jpg");
$red = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 0, 0);

if( isset($_GET["x"]) && isset($_GET["y"]) ) {
  // the map is GTA SAn andreas is 6000x6000
  // the image that i use is 800x800 6000/800 = 7.5

  $x = $_GET["x"]/7.5;
  $y = $_GET["y"]/7.5;

  // 0.0 0.0 is at the center of the map, in PHP 0.0 0.0 is in the top left corner, so I added / substracted 400. the map is 800x800 px, 400x400 is at the center of the map.

  $x = $x + 400;
  $y = -($y - 400);

  imagefilledrectangle($img, $x, $y, $x+10, $y + 10, $red);
}

header ('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
?>
```

How i can make this? The MySQL connection isn't make. I use PDO.
The link for my try is: https://panel.bigzone.ro/map/273.914/-1775.53 .
You can show me how I can make this? Thanks for view this post.Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to show multiple points on a single image. However, I have no idea what your question really is.

Comment: How can i create more points on a single image with coordinates loaded from MySQL database. I have these collumns in MySQL: ID, X, Y where X and Y are the coordinates.

Comment: There is nothing in your code that would help us get started. You need to share what you have tried to solve your own question and what was wrong with that attempt and we will help you to fix your code.  Pls do not expect us to write the entire code for you from scratch.

Comment: I want only one example tohel